# Track use of a function using SQlite3

Tags: python, function, sqlite, file-transfer

I'm new to programming, and am using Python to write a function that transfers files created or modified in the last 24 hours. I now need to figure out how to use a SQlite3 database to keep track of the time and date of last file transfer. I know how to create a database and table in SQlite3, but am at a loss when it comes to tying it to the file transfer function. This is the code for my file transfer:

```
    import os,time
    import datetime
    import shutil
    import datetime as dt
    conn = sqlite3.connect('file_check.db')
    c = conn.cursor()


    now = dt.datetime.now()
    ago = now-dt.timedelta(hours=24)
    strftime = "%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"
    created = ('C:\\Users\\Jacqueline\\Desktop\\created')
    dest = ('C:\\Users\\Jacqueline\\Desktop\\dest')

    def file_trans(created, dest):
        for root, dirs,files in os.walk(created):  
            for fname in files:
                path = os.path.join(root, fname)
                st = os.stat(path)    
                mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
                if mtime > ago:
                    print("True:  ", fname, " at ", mtime.strftime("%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"))
                    shutil.move(path, dest)
                    c.execute("INSERT INTO FileCheck (unix, datestamp, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?)", (unix, datestamp, timestamp))
                    conn.commit
    conn.close


    def main(source, destination):
    # parameters passed into file_trans
        source = created
        destination = dest
        #call file_trans
        file_trans(source, destination)


    if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

Any ideas on how to link this somehow to an SQlite3 table so I can track when the file transfers have taken place? My code for creating the database is:

```
    import sqlite3
    import time
    import datetime #creates datestamp
    import random   #creates value

    conn = sqlite3.connect("file_check.db")   #defines connection
    c = conn.cursor()


    def create_table():
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FileCheck(unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, timestamp TEXT)")


    def dynamic_data_entry():
        unix = time.time()                                                                                         #timestamp
        datestamp = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))                     #formats datestamp
        timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))                                                                    
        c.execute("INSERT INTO FileCheck (unix, datestamp, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?)",             
          (unix, datestamp, timestamp))
        conn.commit()

    create_table()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

The table is fine-- I just need to link it to the function.

Comment: You already got the time and date in ``now``, and you know how to create the sqlite3 db, so it's simply an ``db.execute("INSERT .....", ...)`` with the appropriate parameters corresponding to your table, at the end of your file_trans function

Comment: How are you interacting with your SQLite database? While it may take a bit to learn, I find SQLAlchemy is an excellent tool when dealing with databases in Python. It is probably overkill for such a simple project, but worth learning in the long run.

Comment: So once the database is created, I just need to reference it in my function? That will allow me to keep track of each time the file transfer is used?

Comment: It might help if you can post the code that you are using to create the DB. Yes, it is generally as simple as creating a cursor, executing an insert statement and then committing the changes - https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: I'll edit the original posting with the database code.

Comment: I've imported sqlite3 and the db, and the file transfer takes place, but isn't recorded as having happened in the db.

Comment: Did you run `conn.commit()` to commit your changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to define the variables you are passing in to your execute statement. If you are still getting errors, post the current code you are using, plus the full stack trace (error message) you are getting. It is surprising how much that can tell people about what is going wrong.

I've also moved the connection creation into the function, so you don't have issues with the connection closing before you call the function.

```
import os,time
import datetime
import shutil
import datetime as dt
import sqlite3

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(hours=24)
strftime = "%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"
created = ('C:\\Users\\Jacqueline\\Desktop\\created')
dest = ('C:\\Users\\Jacqueline\\Desktop\\dest')

def file_trans(created, dest):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('file_check.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    for root, dirs,files in os.walk(created):  
        for fname in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fname)
            st = os.stat(path)    
            mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
            if mtime > ago:
                print("True:  ", fname, " at ", mtime.strftime("%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"))
                shutil.move(path, dest)
                unix = time.time()
                datestamp = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
                timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%H:%M:%S')) 
                c.execute("INSERT INTO FileCheck (unix, datestamp, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?)", (unix, datestamp, timestamp))
                conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: This worked like a dream. Thanks so much! And thanks for the best practices tip, too.

Comment: No worries, glad we got it figured out. :)